# How to prevent Gradle from compressing .txt files?

Tags: android, json, android-gradle-plugin, android-drawable, android-fileprovider

I have the following configuration: a `FileProvider` from one application that provider other application files of type **drawables** and other text files that contain **json** structure.

Now all this configuration work and I receive a **content uri** (content://...) from one application at the other for both types of files.

What I don't know is how can I recognize on the receiver application what type of file it's received (**drawable** or **json** .txt) and how to convert properly the uri to one of this file types.

This is the current activity of the receiver application:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView listView;
Cursor cursor;
Button bShowImageFiles, bShowJsonFiles;
Context mContext;

//TODO: Densities
static final String DENSITY_LOW = "ldpi";
static final String DENSITY_MEDIUM = "mdpi";
static final String DENSITY_HIGH = "hdpi";
static final String DENSITY_XHIGH = "xhdpi";
static final String DENSITY_XXHIGH = "xxhdpi";

public static final String FILES = "video";
public static final String PROVIDER_AUTHORITY = "some.authority";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_AUTHORITY + "/");
public static Uri FILES_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_AUTHORITY + "/" + FILES  + "/");
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mContext = this;
    bShowImageFiles = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bShowImageFiles);
    bShowJsonFiles = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bShowJsonFiles);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    final String[] from = { "_id", "fileName" };
    final int[] to = { R.id.textViewID, R.id.textFileName };

    bShowImageFiles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            configureFilesUri(getImageDirString(mContext));
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(getImageFilesUri(mContext), null, null, null, null);
            SimpleCursorAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
            listView.setAdapter(sAdapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener());
        }
    });


    bShowJsonFiles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            configureFilesUri(getJsonDirString());
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(getJsonFilesUri(), null, null, null, null);
            SimpleCursorAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
            listView.setAdapter(sAdapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public class ListListener implements OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fileName"));
        Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(FILES_URI + name);

        Log.i("DEBUG:", "path: " + fileUri);

        String type = getMimeType(name);
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
            convertInputStreamToFile(inputStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static String getMimeType(String uri) {
    String extension = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("."));
    String mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(extension);
    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(mimeTypeMap);
    return mimeType;
}


public static String getImageDirString(Context aContext) {
    return "drawable-" + getDeviceDpiName(aContext);
}

public static String getJsonDirString() {
    return "json";
}

public static Uri getImageFilesUri(Context aContext) {
    return Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_AUTHORITY + "/" + getImageDirString(aContext) + "/");
}

public static Uri getJsonFilesUri() {
    return Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_AUTHORITY + "/" + getJsonDirString() + "/");
}

public static String getDeviceDpiName(Context aContext) {
    int density = aContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
    String dpi;

    switch(density)
    {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            dpi =  DENSITY_LOW;
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            dpi = DENSITY_MEDIUM;
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            dpi = DENSITY_HIGH;
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
            dpi = DENSITY_XHIGH;
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
            dpi = DENSITY_XXHIGH;
            break;
        default:
            dpi = DENSITY_HIGH;
            break;
    }
    return dpi;
}

private void configureFilesUri(String filesPath) {
    FILES_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_AUTHORITY + "/" + filesPath  + "/");
}

private void convertInputStreamToFile( InputStream aInputStream) {
    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/kibo");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "bubu.png");

    try {
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        //read from is to buffer
        while((bytesRead = aInputStream.read(buffer)) !=-1){
            os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        aInputStream.close();
        //flush OutputStream to write any buffered data to file
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("DEBUG", "******* File not found. Did you" +
                " add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the   manifest?");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Explanation:** So you can see that currently I transfer the `Uri` to `InputStream` that in it's turn gets converted to file using an `FileOutputStream`. And this works as long as I get drawables files from the second project. But if I get a json file the application crashes because the `InputStream` I getting from this file is null for some reason.

**UPDATE (19.11.14):** After additional research I realized that the reason that I can't get an InputStream for the **.txt** files is because they are getting compressed at compile time (as opposed to the drawable **.png** files which is already a compressed format)

**So the question is:** How to prevent gradle from compressing .txt files that are located in the assets folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that it was the compression after all. Adding the following:

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress 'txt', '.txt', 'json', '.json'
}
```

to the **build.gradle** file allows you to disable compression on specific file types in your project in the assets folder. You can get more information in the following link:

[aaptOptions](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-aapt-options)

Answer (score 0):

In order access files in the assets folder you can get the InputStream like this:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("<filename>");
```

*filename* may be a filename including the path in your assets folder.

So for loading a file that resides in "assets/json-files/example.json" you would do

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("assets/json-files/example.json");
```

Comment: As the question specified I don't have a direct access to the assets folder because it's not part of my project. It's part of a second application that will provide the first application with additional files that it holds in the assets folder using the FileProvider mechanism.